# How can I restrict html upload files to only take camera photo?

Tags: html, forms, input, upload

I have an upload element input with HTML to upload images. How can I change it so the user can only use the upload on their phone and do it so they don’t have the upload option, they have to take photo at the time?

Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Anyone got an answer?